# New PC, monitor gets no signal unless swapped after boot

Tags: boot, display, resolution

My new pc does not work with my widescreen monitor - the monitor stays in power save mode.

- The pc does work with another monitor (4:3).
- If I boot with the 4:3 (OK) and then swap to the widescreen, the
  widescreen works.
- If I boot with the widescreen (not OK) and then swap to the 4:3,
  there is no monitor signal.

I am using onboard graphic (VGA). I have tried changing related BIOS settings (eg Initial Display). The widescreen does not seem to have any power saving options to change, and auto-detect does nothing.

I need to be able to boot with the widescreen (I must return my neighboiurs 4:3!). Please can anyone explain what might be happening and how, if possible, it might be resolved.

---

*Motherboard: [GIGABYTE H110M-DS2](http://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H110M-DS2-rev-10)*

*Samsung 2243SN monitor (widescreen)*

*Acer monitor (4:3)*

*Debian Jessie*

---

EDITED TO ADD

The widescreen monitor works fine on two other PCs.

Comment: Are you really trying to run a monitor at 1920x1080 over VGA? Probably time to invest in an up-to-date monitor and connect over HDMI or DVI-D.

Comment: The motherboard is OK up to 1920 x 1200. The monitor works fine on other PCs.